# How to exclude first 2 posts from a specific category for a custom post type archive page

Tags: php, pre-get-posts, exclude

I have a custom post type, `product` with various categories. On the archive page for this post type, I would like to exclude the first 2 posts tagged with the "Featured" category (ID `7`) from being displayed within the loop. All other products, including any other products tagged with "Featured," should show in the loop.

Here's where I'm at so far:

```
function exclude_first_two_from_cat($query) {

    if( !is_admin() && $query->is_post_type_archive('product') ) {
        // Get the IDs of the first 2 products with featured category
        $exclude_post_ids = get_posts(array(
            'posts_per_page' => 2,
            'cat'   => '7',
        ));
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', (array) $exclude_post_ids ); 
    }

}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_first_two_from_cat', 50);
```

For some reason the `get_posts` call does not seem to be querying only the `product` post type. I tried adding `'post_type' => 'product'` but that results in a 500 error (I'm assuming because I'm already using the `is_post_type_archive` conditional.